# Ngram Implementation

Tags: c++, n-gram

How can I implement ngrams in C++?

for example;

TEXT

bi-grams: *T, TE, EX, XT, T*
tri-grams: *TE, TEX, EXT, XT*, T__

Thank You

Comment: SO isn't really a code writing service.  What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried to write codes to have those ngrams. I can tokenize the words in a sentence, but I couldn't do this one. Is there a ready library for that?

Comment: An ngram is just a substring of length n. It’s totally unclear what your problem is. Extracting substrings from a string surely isn’t a problem, or is it?

Comment: I think it is a problem. How can I write codes for that?

Comment: @Sermet : [`std::string::substr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr)...

Answer (score 1):

This [library](http://code.google.com/p/ngrams/) may be useful:

> ngrams
>
> A package in C++ for character or word ngram analysis. It uses Ternary
>   Search Tree instead of hashing table for faster ngram frequency
>   counting. Words are converted to unique IDs and encoded to more
>   compact base 256 integers. It is a partial implementation of Dr. Vlado
>   Keselj 's Text-Ngrams 1.6, which is a very flexible Ngram package in
>   perl.

Example:

```
$ cat tst
TEST

$ ./ngrams --type=character --n=3 --in=tst
ngrams have been generated, start outputing.
BEGIN OUTPUT
Total 11 unique ngram in 12 ngrams.
Total 11 unique ngram in 12 ngrams.
1-GRAMS ( Total 4 unique ngrams in 5 grams )
1-GRAMS ( Total 4 unique ngrams in 5 grams )
------------------------
T   2
E   1
S   1
_   1

2-GRAMS ( Total 4 unique ngrams in 4 grams )
2-GRAMS ( Total 4 unique ngrams in 4 grams )
------------------------
ES  1
ST  1
TE  1
T_  1

3-GRAMS ( Total 3 unique ngrams in 3 grams )
3-GRAMS ( Total 3 unique ngrams in 3 grams )
------------------------
EST 1
ST_ 1
TES 1

Subtotal: 0 seconds for generating ngrams.
Subtotal: 0 seconds for outputing ngrams.
Total 0 seconds.
```

Comment: It's a library, source included. There's a sample application in the package called 'ngrams. You can build the library and sample application with 'make'. You can run the sample application like the example shown, using a test file called 'tst' which as shown just includes the sample string 'TEST'.

Comment: Could you send me the link please?